# pylsp times out over TRAMP

Tags: python, microsoft-windows, tramp, lsp-mode, lsp

I'm (unfortunately and against my will) using Windows 10 running Emacs 28.1 attempting to connect to a remote Ubuntu machine via TRAMP (currently this happens to be WSL but there are other Linux servers I'll do remote development with so am using TRAMP). I initially had an issue even connecting remotely but fixed that using [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1845#issuecomment-699169414) and can now connect but cannot find definitions or really do anything - it just times out.

I am using `pyenv` but haven't gotten the Emacs integration working so to find the correct `pylsp` I added this script in `$HOME/.local/bin/tramp_pylsp_wrapper`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

## Wrapper for connecting with TRAMP to source pyenv and
## start python language server
##
## This is a bandaid. Should find a better solution

set -e

PYENV_TO_USE=pylsp-test


# Set up pyenv
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init - )"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1

pyenv shell $PYENV_TO_USE

pylsp "$@"
```

My TRAMP configuration is below:

```el
(use-package tramp
  :config
  (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/home/connorfuhrman/.local/bin")
  (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path) 
  (when (eq window-system 'w32)
    (setq tramp-default-method "plink")))
```

and my `lsp-mode` setup is below:

```el
;; LSP setup
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :commands lsp lsp-deferred
  :hook (python-mode . lsp-deferred)
  :config
  (progn
    ;;(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp)
    (lsp-register-client
     (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-tramp-connection "tramp_pylsp_wrapper")
                      :major-modes '(python-mode)
                      :remote? t
                      :server-id 'tramp_pylsp_wrapper-remote))))
(setq lsp-response-timeout 30)
(setq lsp-log-io t)
;; Dirty hack for TRAMP lsp issues
;; from https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1845#issuecomment-699169414
(defun lsp--make-message@override (params)
  "Create a LSP message from PARAMS, after encoding it to a JSON string."
  (let ((body (lsp--json-serialize params)))
    (concat "Content-Length: "
            (number-to-string (+ 2 (string-bytes body))) ;; dirty fix for pyls remote (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1845#issuecomment-699169414)
            ;;(number-to-string (1+ (string-bytes body)))
            "\r\n\r\n"
            body
            "\n")))
(advice-add 'lsp--make-message :override #'lsp--make-message@override)
```

`pylsp` seems to start just fine and I do see the process running and nothing at `/tmp/tramp_pylsp_wrapper-remote-1-stderr` but I cannot do any navigation everything just seems to be timing out:

```
Cancelling textDocument/codeAction(24) in hook post-command-hook
Cancelling textDocument/codeAction(26) in hook post-command-hook
Cancelling textDocument/codeAction(28) in hook post-command-hook
Cancelling textDocument/codeAction(40) in hook post-command-hook
```

and the debugger when set to auto-debug on error shows

```el
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Timeout while waiting for response.  Method: textDocument/definition")
  error("Timeout while waiting for response.  Method: %s" "textDocument/definition")
  lsp-request("textDocument/definition" (:textDocument (:uri "file:////home/connorfuhrman/pylsp-testing/test.py") :position (:line 9 :character 7)))
  lsp-find-locations("textDocument/definition" nil :display-action nil)
  lsp-find-definition()
  funcall-interactively(lsp-find-definition)
  call-interactively(lsp-find-definition)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xb04039385fac28a>)()
  apply(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xb04039385fac28a>) nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 0 1000 nil #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xb04039385fac28a>) nil idle 0 nil])
```

and even with the timeout set to `nil` and letting it go for around 30 minutes while I ate lunch did not result in a response.

The io logs can be found at https://pastebin.com/UQYJpvd6.

I'm worried that somehow the hack I copied and pasted is doing something funky but honestly I don't know enough Elisp to know for sure.